# Execution of the macro does not work (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel, vba

We are running Excel 2016 on a reporting server, (Macro Settings: Enable all macros) and are facing following issue: wenn we manually start the macro (click on green arrow), everything works fine and the code gets executed. But, if we start the Macro via task scheduler, Excel just opens, loads some time and that's it. What could be the cause for this issue?

Comment: How does the macro usually get called? Is it in the workbook on open event? If not use vbscript to open the workbook and execute the macro and the task scheduler to run the vbscript instead of opening the workbook

Comment: Isn't that obvious? If you start it using task scheduler, you don't press the green arrow, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yess task scheduler triggers an event

Comment: Yes, the macro gets called in the Workbook_Open Sub Procedure. There it should load the Macro which is running the cascade, but somehow the macro just doesn't get executed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load through the scheduler, try VB:

```
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xlObj.Workbooks.Open CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") & "\Documents\FILENAME.xlsb" 
xlObj.Run "MODULENAME.MACRONAME"
```

This allows you to call the specific macro to be run.  Note that my file location uses *userprofile* so it can be dynamic to who is opening the file, though it directs to that profiles documents folder.

If you don't want to go through another language with the scheduler, you would want to set-up your macro in the workbook to execute on workbook open, so if the workbook is opened, boom you're started.

Comment: It's already set up to execute on workbook_open, but the macro somehow doesn't get executed. So the event triggers, opens the workbook and... that's it. No macro gets executed. We have the same environment on 2 other reporting servers and there it works smoothly.